ASP.NET Core Web API response management
I have a requirement for my ASP.NET Core Web API project that is the end-user will call one endpoint in the API called api/ControlDevice.
This endpoint will internally call the third party API to do some specific task so I want to wait for 2-3 seconds to get response.
If in 2-3 seconds, I got response from third party API, I will return same response to end-user.
If in 2-3 seconds, I didn't get any response from third party API, then I will return an error message to the user and in background I will store the third party API response that I got after 2-3 seconds.
Currently I am in trouble that how can I manage this usecase in my code.
Thank you for any type for help or suggestion or code demo.

Since either way you want to wait for a response on the backend, I would have the backend notify the frontend when it's finished.  Then let the frontend perform the other logic.  (after 2-3 seconds if no response, (timeout) show error... when it is done, frontend does x action  ??)

Updated

It is not very complicated. You need a service to make the call, then you handle the response.
public class ThirdCallService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public ThirdCallService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> CallThirdPartyApiAsync(string url, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        var temp = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        try
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url, temp.Token);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Then you register the service.
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ThirdCallService>();

Your controller to handle the response.
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ThirdCallService _thirdCallService;

    public SampleApiController(ThirdCallService thirdCallService)
    {
        _thirdCallService = thirdCallService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ControlDevice()
    {
        string thirdPartyUrl = "https://ThirdApi.com";
        int timeoutInSeconds = 2;
        var thirdPartyTask = _thirdCallService.CallThirdPartyApiAsync(thirdPartyUrl, timeoutInSeconds);

        // Previous code
        //if (await Task.WhenAny(thirdPartyTask, Task.Delay(timeoutInSeconds* 1000)) == thirdPartyTask)
        //    {
        //        // within timeout
        //        var result = await thirdPartyTask;
        //        return Ok(result);
        //    }

        //// no within timeout
        //_ = Task.Run(async () =>
        //    {
        //        var delayedResult = await _thirdCallService.CallThirdPartyApiAsync(thirdPartyUrl, timeoutInSeconds * 2);
        //        if (delayedResult != null)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine(delayedResult);
        //        }
        //    });

        if (await Task.WhenAny(thirdPartyTask, Task.Delay(timeoutInSeconds * 1000)) == thirdPartyTask)
        {
            // within timeout
            var result = await thirdPartyTask;
            if (result != null)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Error in processing the request.");
            }
        }

        //Noticed that your tag hangfire, it provides fire-and-forget service, configure as you wish
        //var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
        //    () => Console.WriteLine("Fire-and-forget!"));

        return StatusCode(408, "Request timed out. Response will be processed in the background.");
    }
}


Thanks for code suggestion.I think we are calling third party API twice in your code.Please correct me if I am wrong

Yes I agree so , it will be called twice if time out, I have modified the code , you are welcome to correct  the mistakes.
